# How to implement Runtime Locales in GWT

Tags: gwt, localization, locale, smartgwt

I am trying to implement Runtime Locales in GWT, But I could not able to get it working. There is very limited documentation available on net. So could you please help me in implementing Runtime Locales in GWT. It will be helpful if someone give an example on how to implement Runtime Locales, because I have already spent lot of time on implementing Runtime Locales. So if somebody explain how to implement it using an example that would be great.

The reason I need Runtime Locale is, I want to get date format, month names and weekdays names based on locale string (Ex : en_US, es_MX etc), I mean I want to obtain Locale object from locale string as it is possible in Java. As of my knowledge we cannot get information about any other locale than the default locale that GWT has loaded. and i don't want to use Compile time Locales because of the compile time overhead and increase on static footprint.

This is the documentation for implementing Locale in GWT which I am referring - http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html

Thanks,

Madhusudhan.

Comment: If you're using the Constants interface to show localized content, just add month names and week days to the corresponding .properties files. If you are not, how are you translating your app? Do you want to translate _only_ week days' and months' names while leaving everything else in English?

Comment: Hi Walen, Thanks for the reply. As I couldn't implement Runtime Locale, I am going to use property file. On login I am sending request to server with the selected locale and getting the date format, month and weekdays names from the properties file. We have resource bundle implementation in place for each language. But we didn't want to  hardcode month and weekdays names in properties file so we tried to get those info from Locale. Now we are going with the properties files only.

Comment: To make it dynamic, you have to include *all* locales into your client code. This means every user will have to load unnecessary code just because they "might" select a different locale - and most users will never change their preferred language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss one important thing about runtime locales:

> [...] all locales that GWT knows about **that inherit from your compile-time locale** will be automatically included [...]
>
> As an example, you might have one set of translations for all of Spanish as spoken in Latin America (`es_419`), yet allow users to choose a country-specific locale such as Argentinian Spanish (`es_AR`).

Note that DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_es_AR **extends** DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_es_419.

But there is a trick that allow you to get date format in any locale by getting  `DateTimeFormatInfo` implementation directly for given locale:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo format = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_es_MX();
format.dateFormatLong(); // d 'de' MMMM 'de' y
```

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for the reply. if i use this option "DateTimeFormatInfo format = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_es_MX();" it kind of static, If i have get date format from for some other locale then i need to instantiate that class. I mean its not dynamic. What i need here is a method to get Locale object by passing locale string. In my application in the login screen user select the locale, So i need to display date format based on the selected locale.